# Search function with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am attempting to create a search function with React using Hooks; this function ideally would search thru the current list of movies, and return the movie title.

```
//setting state for the search, and search results
export function Home() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
...

// filter being used to search thru realist given back
useEffect(() => {
    const results = movie.filter(movie =>
      movie.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [searchTerm]);
....
//returning the value in my search box
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
      setSearch(e.target.value);
  };
...

//showing all genres under carousel, these genres are clickable which bring you to the other titles that are associated with that genre
    const genreList = genres.map((item, index) => {
        return(
            <li className='list-inline-item' key={index}>
                <button type='button' className='btn' style={{ color: 'tomato' }} onClick={(e) =>{
                    handleGenre(item.id)
                }}>
                    {item.name}
                </button>
            </li>
        );
    });
//shows the movies under that genre after you click on a specific genre
    const movieList = movieByGenre.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div className='col-md-3 col-sm-6' key={index}>
                <div className='card>'>
                <Link to={`/movie/${item.id}`}>
                    <img className='img-fluid' src={item.poster} alt={item.title}></img>
                </Link>
                <div className='mt-3'>
                <h5> Rated: {item.rating}  </h5>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        );
    });
...
 <label className='search' htmlFor='search'> SEARCH </label>
        <br/>
        <input type='text'
         className='movie-search-bar' 
         placeholder='type movie title' 
         value={search} 
         onChange={handleSearch}>
         </input>
...
//attempting to map over movie list
    <div className='row mt-3'> {searchResults.map ({movieList})}</div>
```

Unable to get anything to return back, assuming its something to do with the way I am attempting to map over my searchResults.

Any input is apprecated!

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly used the variable `searTerm` instead of using `search`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const results = movie.filter(movie =>
      movie.toLowerCase().includes(search)
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [search]);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, that did correct an error.  Now im just getting ```Line 21:21:  'movie' is not defined```

Comment: Where are you getting the list of movies?

Comment: sorry I updated question to show where this information is being returned from, they are specifically being mapped over by their genres to return movie titles associated with that genre

Comment: What are you trying to do here `<div className='row mt-3'> {searchResults.map ({movieList})}</div>`?

Comment: attempting to use my search function to map over the current movies and return the movie that matches the title I put in.

Answer (score 0):

From scraps you shared I can tell that array function `map` expects function to be passed as argument. It looks like you've just passed some object into it. Other clue might be same name for array you are filtering and filtered object `movie.filter(movie =>`. Js might loose it there, but you haven't mentioned any app crush so it might just be your description fault :D